# Active_Shipping Negotiated Rates for UPS - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, shopify

I've integrated the Shopify active_shipping gem into my site and I am trying to get negotiated rates from my UPS account (I can get regular rates). I can't find any documentation on the negotiated rates. Can anyone help me out here? I think this line of code should work but it doesn't produce any errors or any different shipping rates.

```
response = carrier.find_rates(origin, destination, packages, {negotiated_rates: true})
```

I ran across this link here but still no luck:

https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/lib/active_shipping/carriers/ups.rb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try assign your UPS account number as `origin_account` in the options.

```
response = carrier.find_rates(origin, destination, packages, {negotiated_rates: true, origin_account: 11111111})
```

https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/lib/active_shipping/carriers/ups.rb#L358

Comment: This didn't work. I am positive that we have negotiated shipping rates enabled for our UPS account and I am also positive that I have the correct account number. I didn't receive any errors but the shipping rates did not change.

Comment: Could you see the http request which it sends out? You could log them with a gem like `httplog`? I guess it is a configuration thing.